# multisearch T-SQL query with nullable parameters

Tags: sql, t-sql, parameters, null

i'm trying to write a query that i can search with multiple parameters (or not search with if they're null).

however, whenever i try to use the code below and feed it an email parameter and a ticketid parameter, it returns both instead of just one.

```
print '' print '*** creating [SP_SELECT_TICKETS_BY_EMAIL_DATE_OR_STATUS]'
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_select_tickets_by_email_date_or_status]
(
    @Email                  [nvarchar](254) = NULL,
    @StartDate              [datetime] = NULL,
    @EndDate                [datetime] = NULL,
    @TicketStatusId         [nvarchar](50) = NULL
)
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT  [TicketId], [Ticket].[UsersId], [Ticket].[TicketStatusId], [TicketTitle], [TicketContext], [TicketDate], [TicketActive], [Users].[Email]
        FROM    [Ticket]
        JOIN    [TicketStatus]
        ON      [Ticket].[TicketStatusId] = [TicketStatus].[TicketStatusId]
        JOIN    [Users]
        ON      [Ticket].[UsersId] = [Users].[UsersId]
        WHERE   (([Ticket].[TicketStatusId] = @TicketStatusId) AND (@TicketStatusId IS NOT NULL))
        AND     (([Users].[Email] = @Email) AND (@Email IS NOT NULL))
        AND     ((([TicketDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND (@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL)) OR (([TicketDate] = @StartDate) AND (@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL)))
    END
GO
```

let me know if any more anymore info is needed! (only reason i'm not adding more at the moment is because i'm certain its just a logic issue i'm overlooking)

EDIT::

I tried modifiying the WHERE clause to below and now its not returning anything. :(

```
        WHERE   (([Ticket].[TicketStatusId] = @TicketStatusId) OR (@TicketStatusId IS NULL AND [Ticket].[TicketStatusId] IS NULL))
        AND     (([Users].[Email] = @Email) OR ([Users].Email) IS NULL AND @Email IS NULL)
        AND     ((([TicketDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR (@StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL AND [TicketDate] IS NULL)) OR (([TicketDate] = @StartDate) OR (@StartDate IS NULL AND [TicketDate] IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL)))
    END
GO
```

Comment: please add tables an d data to https://dbfiddle.uk/rmaqsBtp

Comment: Just a comment here, start small find out why email is not working by removing all the other conditions.

Once email is working as required move on to another parameter... may make your life a bit simpler.

Also I think you want to change your joins to left joins

Comment: @Krik that'll be my next move i think :)

Comment: @nbk here's with the tables https://dbfiddle.uk/hu1Vgz1t 

edit: here's withhthe tables and sample data (though its getting mad about TicketTitle) https://dbfiddle.uk/9T0dQRfK

Comment: Don't use double quotes as a synonym to single quotes. Unlike other languages, both are very different in the SQL language. All string literals should use single quotes. Identifiers like table/column names can optionally use double quotes.

Comment: Please explain desired result. To me, *it returns both instead of just one* is not clear. What is *it*? Maybe illustrate with sample data. So you want records with that email *or* that ticketid?

Comment: @Parfait so its returning all rows that have the passed in email (any tickets by tom@company.com) OR the passed in ticketstatus (any with 'Open' status, not strictly by tom@company.com) rather than both the email and ticketstatus (Open tickets by tom@company.com)

Comment: Please show how you called the stored proc to receive that result. Re-reading your logic and counting parentheses, I cannot see how that is possible. Please carefully check what you posted here and actually ran on your end.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want lots of `OR` conditions.

I strongly suggest you use dynamic SQL for this kind of search, in order to hit indexes correctly. Note that you should still parameterize the SQL as shown.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_select_tickets_by_email_date_or_status
    @Email                  nvarchar(254) = NULL,
    @StartDate              datetime = NULL,
    @EndDate                datetime = NULL,
    @TicketStatusId         nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT
  t.TicketId,
  t.UsersId,
  t.TicketStatusId,
  t.TicketTitle,
  t.TicketContext,
  t.TicketDate,
  ts.TicketActive,
  u.Email
FROM Ticket t
JOIN TicketStatus ts ON t.TicketStatusId = ts.TicketStatusId
JOIN Users u ON t.UsersId = u.UsersId
';

SELECT @sql +=
  ISNULL(
    'WHERE ' + STRING_AGG(cond, '
OR '),
  '')
FROM (
    SELECT 't.TicketStatusId = @TicketStatusId'
    WHERE @TicketStatusId IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'u.Email = @Email'
    WHERE @Email IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 't.TicketDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND ISNULL(@EndDate, @StartDate)'
    WHERE @StartDate IS NOT NULL
) t(cond);

PRINT @sql; -- your friend

EXEC sp_executsql @sql,
  N'@Email                  nvarchar(254),
    @StartDate              datetime,
    @EndDate                datetime,
    @TicketStatusId         nvarchar(50)',

    @Email = @Email,
    @StartDate = @StartDate,
    @EndDate = @EndDate,
    @TicketStatusId = @TicketStatusId;
```

Note also that I have used table aliases, and removed all the unnecessary quoting. Check the aliases as some of them were unclear from your post.

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition to your `WHERE` clause:

```
len(trim(@TicketStatusId))> 0 and  len(trim(@Email))> 0
```

In case the `@TicketStatusId` or `@Email` is entered as '' or just space.

Comment: Emails and TicketStatusId are both retrieved through a dropdown, so it's either gonna be like "tomsmith@company.com" or NULL. I gave it a run anywho, but still the same issue. :( Still, appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

Should have some default values as fallback for nulls - or enforce values in your data, i.e. `NOT NULL`.

There is some good reading on that here: [Why you Should Always Specify Whether a Column Accepts Nulls](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/why-you-should-always-specify-whether-a-column-accepts-nulls)

Meanwhile, is probably best to make sure at least your variables are populated before you use them in your script, will make things simpler for start, something like this:

```sql
IF @TicketStatusId IS NULL SET @TicketStatusId = -1 -- I'd pressume your TicketStatusId is an INT, not an NVARCHAR as your procedure suggests? Change accordingly...
IF @Email IS NULL SET @Email = 'default@email' -- any string that's unlikely to be in your database should do
IF @StartDate IS NULL SET @StartDate = GETDATE() -- current date for this example
IF @EndDate IS NULL SET @EndDate = '2099-12-31'  -- typically you want a date far in the future

SELECT
    [TicketId], [Ticket].[UsersId], [Ticket].[TicketStatusId], [TicketTitle], [TicketContext], [TicketDate], [TicketActive], [Users].[Email]
FROM
    [Ticket]
    JOIN [TicketStatus] ON [Ticket].[TicketStatusId] = [TicketStatus].[TicketStatusId]
    JOIN [Users] ON [Ticket].[UsersId] = [Users].[UsersId]
WHERE
    ISNULL([Ticket].[TicketStatusId], @TicketStatusId) = @TicketStatusId
    AND ISNULL([Users].[Email], @Email) = @Email
    AND ISNULL([TicketDate], @StartDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```